# item change NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Can you please tell me the file string entered in the array, and then you have to change an element in this array. doing so:

```
NSMutableArray *user;
...
NSString* filePath1 = @"user";
        NSString* fileRoot1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:filePath1 ofType:@"txt"];
        NSString* fileContents1 =[NSMutableString stringWithContentsOfFile:fileRoot1 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
        user = [fileContents1 componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
        money= [user[0] intValue]-2;
        user[0]=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",money];
```

swears

```
- [__NSArrayI ReplaceObjectAtIndex: withObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x12fd4270
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-DontLinkElementID_52) return a [`NSArray`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) even if you local variable is a mutable array the value returned is not. So you will need to create a mutable copy.
Just can easily do this by call the `mutableCopy` on [`NSArray`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html):

```
    user = [[fileContents1 componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet] mutableCopy];
```